# "Reparent" classes from compiled code

Tags: c++, qt, multiple-inheritance

Following case:
Let's say there is a binary library which defines the class "Base", and many subclasses ("Derivative1", "Derivative2" etc) of it.

I want to extend these subclasses in my own code, but because my extensions are the same for all subclasses as they only deal with parts of Base, it would be tedious to subclass every Derivative class and add the same code over and over again.

My first idea was to simply write a class template which would do the work for me, but because the library I'm dealing with is Qt, QObject has foiled me.
My second idea was to use macros to generate each class structure, but this was also thwarted by moc.

The "reparent" in the title is because I thought of deriving from Base and creating BaseExtended, and then somehow tell the compiler to reparent every Derivative to this extended class. Isn't there a way to for example declare the "Base" in "BaseExtended" virtual, and then just write

```
class Derivative1Extended : public Derivative1, public BaseExtended {}
```

and have the virtual Base in BaseExtended point to the Base in Derivative1, thus basically "squeezing ing" my extensions between Base and Derivative1?

(By the way, I tried to keep the above as generic as possible,  but what I'm actually doing is trying add signals for "focusIn" and "focusOut" to every QWidget derivative without writing the same code over and over again for every QWidget subclass I use)

EDIT:
For reference, here's my current implementation:

```
// qwidgetfs.h
class QLineEditFS : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *);
    void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *);

public:
    QLineEditFS(QWidget *parent = 0);
signals:
    void focusReceived(QWidgetFS::InputType);
    void focusLost();
};

// qwidgetfs.cpp
QLineEditFS::QLineEditFS(QWidget *parent /*= 0*/)
    : QLineEdit(parent)
{}

void QLineEditFS::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *e)
{
    QLineEdit::focusInEvent(e);
    emit focusReceived(QWidgetFS::InputText);
}

void QLineEditFS::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *e)
{
    QLineEdit::focusOutEvent(e);
    emit focusLost();
}
```

And this repeated for QSpinBoxFS, QComboBoxFS, QCheckBoxFS and so on...
Instead I would like to just define this logic in a common class QWidgetFS, and then "inject" it into other classes derived from QWidget

Comment: What would you do with all these signals?

Comment: You're going to have quite some issues with `bool QObject::inherits(char const* className)`

Comment: @Mat Right now, it's for managing a virtual onscreen keyboard, but I also had other use cases in mind, like for example highlighting the label left to any input widget if it has focus

Comment: Btw., I just found a [thread](http://www.qtforum.org/article/13381/multiple-inheritance-and-qobject.html) describing exactly the same problem I'm having, and according to them what I'm trying to do is more or less impossible

Comment: I think the real issue here is that you're asking about a solution, without telling us what the real problem is. IOW: It's a very unproductive way *for you* to ask questions -- you're unlikely to get the answer you're looking for. The real question you had is: How can I catch changes in focus state of arbitrary QWidgets. Posing it that way might have even led you to event filters yourself.

Comment: @KubaOber My question was "how can I point a vitual base class of a derivative to a non-virtual base class in another derivative", but I mentioned qt so people would know why both macros and templates were a no-go for my problem. I guess I mixed in my intentions with this question too much, but I'm still very grateful that people tried to suggest solutions

Comment: The problem is that QObject isn't a virtual base class in the first place.  You can't change this from outside code, since all code in the Qt library already knows the static type of QObject derived superclasses.  You'd need to modify Qt to make it virtual and it would probably break Qt quite badly by making it virtual, since it makes some assumptions about object layout IIRC, and apart from that would hurt performance for little gain.

Comment: @Pete I see, that's what I've been assuming.. Put this in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you'll really be able to do what you are suggesting without modifying Qt and recompiling it.

Perhaps to do what you want, you could use event filters installed on the objects that you want to handle focus events from?

little test app:

header:

```
class FocusEventFilter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FocusEventFilter(QObject* parent)
        : QObject(parent)
    {}

Q_SIGNALS:
    void focusIn(QWidget* obj, QFocusEvent* e);
    void focusOut(QWidget* obj, QFocusEvent* e);

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e);
};

class testfocus : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    testfocus(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~testfocus();

public Q_SLOTS:
    void onFocusIn(QWidget*, QFocusEvent*);
    void onFocusOut(QWidget*, QFocusEvent*);

private:
    Ui::testfocusClass ui;
};
```

Implementation

```
#include <QFocusEvent>
#include "testfocus.h"

bool FocusEventFilter::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e)
{
    if (e->type() == QEvent::FocusIn) {
        bool r = QObject::eventFilter(obj, e);
        QFocusEvent *focus = static_cast<QFocusEvent*>(e);
        QWidget* w = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(obj);
        if (w) {
            emit focusIn(w, focus);
        }
        return r;
    } 
    else if (e->type() == QEvent::FocusOut) {
        bool r = QObject::eventFilter(obj, e);
        QFocusEvent *focus = static_cast<QFocusEvent*>(e);
        QWidget* w = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(obj);
        if (w) {
            emit focusOut(w, focus);
        }
        return r;
    } 
    else {
        // standard event processing
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, e);
    }
}


testfocus::testfocus(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    FocusEventFilter* filter = new FocusEventFilter(this);

    ui.lineEdit->installEventFilter(filter);
    ui.lineEdit_2->installEventFilter(filter);

    connect(filter, SIGNAL(focusIn(QWidget*, QFocusEvent*)), this, SLOT(onFocusIn(QWidget*, QFocusEvent*)));
    connect(filter, SIGNAL(focusOut(QWidget*, QFocusEvent*)), this, SLOT(onFocusOut(QWidget*, QFocusEvent*)));
}

testfocus::~testfocus()
{

}

void testfocus::onFocusIn(QWidget* obj, QFocusEvent*)
{
    obj->setStyleSheet("background-color:#aaaaff;");

}

void testfocus::onFocusOut(QWidget* obj, QFocusEvent*)
{
    obj->setStyleSheet("background-color:#ffaaaa;");
}
```

Of course, YMMV.  You could always have a separate filter per object.  This method means you can avoid deriving from everything.  Not as efficient but it should work.

You may be able to do what you want in the event filter itself rather than using signals/slots.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I don't get your example, but this suggestion would still require me to derive a new class for every widget that I want to add the extension, no? Also, in that case (which is what I'm currently also doing), your code seems kinda complex (see my edit)

Comment: @Ancurio: no, you install one event filter on all widgets you are interested in. You don't need any new widget classes for this.

Comment: @Mat ahh, yes, now I see what your code is doing. Thanks! I will definitely consider this

Comment: It gets better: you can enumerate all child widgets in your application's window(s), and apply the event filters on them automatically. Note that an event filter is just a QObject, it does not (and normally should not) derive from QWidget.

Answer (score 1):

I have done stuff like this in the past with templates. The problem is that you can't use signals.

I'm typing this up without a compiler so please be kind :):

```
template<typename T>
class FSWidget: public T
{
public:
    FSWidget()
    {
        _delegate = NULL;
    }

    setDelegate(FSDelegate *delegate)
    {
        _delegate = delegate;
    }

protected:
    virtual void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *e)
    {
        T::focusInEvent(e);
        if (_delegate) {
            _delegate->focusInEvent(this);
        }
    }

    virtual void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *e)
    {
        T::focusOutEvent(e);
        if (_delegate) {
            _delegate->focusOutEvent(this);
        }

    }

private:
    FSDelegate *_delegate;
};
```

So, the advantage is when you need to use this you can basically create a class like this:

```
FSWidget<QLineEdit *> lineEdit = new FSWidget<QLineEdit *>;
lineEdit->setDelegate(delegate);
```

You can put in whatever you want instead of QLineEdit and it will work.

And then teh FSDelegate could be just an interface that you mix into whatever class needs to act on the info. It could be one of these:

```
class FSDelegate
{
public:
    virtual void focusInEvent(QWidget *w) = 0;
    virtual void focusOutEvent(QWidget *w) = 0;
};
```

If you're always doing the same thing in on focusInEvent and focusOutEvents, you can implement these functions and make a real Mixin class.

Hopefully this can avoid some code duplication for you.